# Selendroid is alwasy looking for default emulator-5560'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, selendroid

Im runing some of my test on cross browser and when i try to do it on Android as on below code ,Some times it gives me an error saying

> Caused by: io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
>   error: dev ice 'emulator-5560' not found

```
public void SetupBrowser(string BrowserName)
        {

            if (BrowserName.Equals("IE"))
            {
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
            else if (BrowserName.Equals("chrome"))
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            else if (BrowserName.Equals("android"))
            {
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
               // capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "FAAZCY04X185");
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.Android());
            }
            else
            {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
        }
```

I tried with `capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "FAAZCY04X185");` but no luck.
So how to provide my actual device to the `DesiredCapabilities`